# Save and immediate retrive of NSManagedObjce from core data giving null object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am saving NSManagedObject in core data as :

```
[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [Book bookWithInfo:book inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSError *error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error in saving");
    }
}
```

and immediate retrieve after this by

```
[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^ {
    Book *item = [Book bookByBookId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentBookId] inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}
```

the bookId(currentBookId) is same saved in bookWithInfo method.
Why I am getting nil item when try to immediately retrieve?

Comment: Could you log the currentBookId before each operation, and show the insertion and fetch code? (If you like to use the item you just inserted, you don't have to re-fetch it, just keep a reference to the inserted item).

Comment: I suppose problem with inserting an object into context. Try debugging  "+[Book bookWithInfo:inManagedObjectContext:]" method or print here some insights of the implementation

Answer (score 0):

NSManagedObjectID is changes after invoking -save: first time after insertion.
For more information about CoreData read about -[NSManagedObject objectID] method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003607).

Comment: This is not related to the question. the fetch after the save is done by another property of the object.

Comment: missed that. Author should specify how does he insert object into NSManagedObjectContext (i.e. insights of "bookWithInfo" method)